# Pulsein not working when share ground

Tags: pulsein

I have 3rd party device that create PWM output which I want to measure it with Arduino, the problem I have is when I shared ground between the two boards which cause the Pulsein output to become zero. (why this is happening, and how to fix it)

The reason I am connecting the ground since I need measure other signals on that board. (All other signals are responding fine)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGaJd8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

code:

```cpp
#define pulse_ip 3
unsigned long duration;
int ontime,offtime,duty;
float freq,period;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(pulse_ip, INPUT);
}
   
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  ontime = pulseIn(pulse_ip, HIGH);
  offtime = pulseIn(pulse_ip, LOW);
  period = ontime + offtime;
  freq = 1000000.0 / period;
  duty = (ontime / period) * 100;
  Serial.print(offtime);
  Serial.print("-");
  Serial.print(ontime);
  Serial.print("-");
  Serial.print(period);
  Serial.print("-");
  Serial.print(freq);
  Serial.print("-");
  Serial.print((duty * 255) / 100);
  Serial.print("-");
  Serial.println(duty);
  delay(1000);
  
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: why I am getting zero when I share the ground

Comment: are you sure you don't get only random pulses without common ground?

Comment: @Juraj that is good point maybe I am getting random, let me double check

Comment: @Juraj Yes I believe you are correct I am getting random numbers and as soon as I share ground become zero

Comment: does calling pulseIn twice make sense? check the reference https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/pulsein/

Comment: `The reason I am connecting the ground since I need measure other signals on that board.` -- no, the reason you connect the grounds is because **you have to**. https://majenko.co.uk/blog/our-blog-1/the-importance-of-sharing-grounds-12

Comment: @Majenko you are of course correct, that was reason I was getting random number

Comment: What (approximate) frequency is the PWM signal? And what voltage levels?

Comment: @Majenko 3.3V is the voltage,  14.56k freq  of pwm

Comment: you should provide a timeout argument so that it runs faster. even then, it's pushing the limits of hardware and CPU speed and will likely be fuzzy/noisy if it works at all. It would be better to use an RC filter to convert the PWM into an analog voltage, then divide that down to 0-5v, then sample the resulting signal. Since you only seem to need 1 sample a second, you can easily use a large capacitor and sample averaging to get a very smooth analog voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Without connected grounds the signal on the input pin you read with pulseIn must be random noise.

Two `pulseIn` one waiting for HIGH change and second waiting for LOW don't make sense because for parameter HIGH, `pulseIn` **waits for the pin to go from LOW to HIGH**, starts timing, **then waits for the pin to go LOW** and stops timing. Then it returns the length of the pulse in microseconds.